# Ionic Checkbox height disproportional

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I'm using the following code to render checkboxes in a row

```
                <label class="row item item-input ">
                <span class="item-text-wrap col col-50 input-label">Type Of Inspection</span>
                <div class="col col-50">
                    <div class="item-text-wrap row responsive-md">
                        <ion-radio  name="typeins" ng-model="form6.type" ng-value="'Monthly'">Monthly</ion-radio>
                        <ion-radio  name="typeins" ng-model="form6.type" ng-value="'Yearly'">Yearly</ion-radio>
                        <ion-radio  name="typeins" ng-model="form6.type" ng-value="'Periodic'">Periodic Discharge</ion-radio></div>
                </div>
            </label>
```

My app's background is black and the checkboxes are white. When the device width/height is lowered as can be seen in [this ionic playground link](http://play.ionic.io/m/90209eabf06e)
the checkbox with more text keeps it's height while the others are shorter than it. The behavior can be seen in the attached screenshot[image: Checkbox height disproportional]. How to make the other's height equal the biggest checkbox?

Answer (score 0):

You can do many things to achieve what you want:
1. Provide min-height for the elements.
2. Hide text-overflow
3. Provide min-width and width to give each element the size to just hold the content

Comment: The "Monthly" and "Yearly" have the same height as "Periodic Discharge". Can be verified from the white border under both where the white border in "Periodic Discharge" is lost in it's own white color.

Comment: It's the default ionic Checkbox behavior which looks OK when the background is the default i.e. White but in my case it's black and that's what is causing the problem

Comment: You have set background-color property for the parent.